# Passing value from html to javascript in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to develop a shopping cart system using kendo-ui mobile and phonegap. First I am listing all the items in a list view. In each listview item, there will be one plus button, minus button and a label.I am using this combination for selecting the quantity of items.So, if we click plus button, the label value should be 0+1=> 1 and when we click minus, it should be like 1-1=>0 .To change the value of label when clicking button, I am passing the id of label to change the corresponding label value. But I am not able to pass the id form html to javascript, like I do in web development. Here is my code,

My listview item template,

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="endless-scrolling-template">



<div class="product">

    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="#=ProductName# image" class="pullImage"/>
    <h3>#:ProductName#</h3>
    <p>$#:kendo.toString(UnitPrice, "c")#</p>
    <a id="minus" data-role="button" data-click="minus(#:ProductID#)" >-</a>
    <label id=#:ProductID#>0</label>
    <a id="plus" data-role="button" data-click="plus(#:ProductID#)" data-name="plus">+</a>
    <a id="loginButton" data-role="button" data-click="login">Add to Cart</a>
    <div class="console"></div>

</div>
```

and my javascript functions,

```
 <script>

 function plus(itemid) {
       var quantity=document.getElementById(itemid).innerHTML;
       document.getElementById(itemid).textContent = parseInt(quantity)+1;
    } 

     function minus(itemid) {
      var quantity=document.getElementById(itemid).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(itemid).textContent = parseInt(quantity)-1;
    } 

</script>
```

Can anyone please tell me what Iam doing wrong here? Or can you provide an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

When using Kendo, you can use Kendo MVVM. When JS objects are wired up in views using Kendo MVVM, when the value of the input elements change, the value of the JS objects reflects the change automatically. So what you need to do is to create a JS model for your view and set it as your view's model using data-model="yourModel". See this link: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/mvvm

In your scenario here I think this link will help you: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/mvvm/source.html

This behavior is explained in the Kendo mobile book I wrote and you can see the checkout screen of the sample application built for the book here: http://movies.kendomobilebook.com/